# Inverse of a matrix with symbolic variables

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

I want to evaluate the inverse of the following colossal matrix

```
m[\[Omega]_, \[CapitalDelta]_] = {{(0. + 0.1 I) + \[Omega], -1., 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, (0.866025 - 0.5 I) \[CapitalDelta], 0, 0, 0, 0}, {-1., \[Omega], -1., 0, 0, 0, (-0.866025 + 0.5 I) \[CapitalDelta], 0, (0. + 1. I) \[CapitalDelta], 0, 0, 0}, {0, -1., \[Omega], -1., 0,0, 0, (0. - 1. I) \[CapitalDelta], 0, (-0.866025 - 0.5 I) \[CapitalDelta], 0, 0}, {0, 0, -1., \[Omega], -1., 0, 0, 0, (0.866025 + 0.5 I) \[CapitalDelta], 0, (0.866025 - 0.5 I) \[CapitalDelta], 0}, {0, 0, 0, -1., \[Omega], -1., 0, 0, 0, (-0.866025 + 0.5 I)\[CapitalDelta],0, (0. + 1. I) \[CapitalDelta]}, {0, 0, 0, 0, -1., (0. + 0.1 I) + \[Omega], 0, 0, 0, 0, (0. - 1. I) \[CapitalDelta], 0}, {0, (-0.866025 - 0.5 I) \[CapitalDelta], 0, 0, 0, 0, (0.3 + 0.1 I) + \[Omega], -1., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {(0.866025 + 0.5 I) \[CapitalDelta], 0, (0. + 1. I) \[CapitalDelta], 0, 0, 0, -1., 0.3 + \[Omega], -1., 0., 0., 0.}, {0, (0. - 1. I) \[CapitalDelta], 0, (0.866025 - 0.5 I) \[CapitalDelta], 0, 0, 0., -1., 0.3 + \[Omega], -1., 0., 0.}, {0, 0, (-0.866025 + 0.5 I) \[CapitalDelta], 0, (-0.866025 - 0.5 I) \[CapitalDelta], 0, 0., 0., -1., 0.3 + \[Omega], -1., 0.}, {0, 0, 0, (0.866025 + 0.5 I) \[CapitalDelta], 0, (0. + 1. I) \[CapitalDelta], 0., 0., 0., -1., 0.3 + \[Omega], -1.}, {0, 0, 0, 0, (0. - 1. I) \[CapitalDelta], 0, 0., 0., 0., 0., -1., (0.3 + 0.1 I) + \[Omega]}}
```

When I do this operation,

```
Inverse[m[\[Omega], \[CapitalDelta]]]
```

it gives an error that the above matrix is singular. However,

```
Inverse[m[\[Omega], 0.1]]
```

gives the correct result. I don't understand, is matrix m singular or not? Though the set delayed approach works,

```
m[\[Omega]_, \[CapitalDelta]_] :=
```

I want to calculate the inverse of this matrix in this step only as in later steps I have numerical integration using this matrix and the set delayed method takes an absurd amount of time. Any comments or suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Is `0.866025` supposed to be $\sqrt{3}/2$? If yes, then I'd highly recommend writing it as such, because your approximation is off by a good amount and might make the whole inversion unstable.

Comment: @Roman I tried that, but it doesn't work. Its still singular.

Comment: try `inv = Inverse[Rationalize[m[\[Omega], \[CapitalDelta]]]]` then `inv /. \[CapitalDelta] -> 0.1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replacing all machine-precision numbers by exact numbers:

```
m[ω_, Δ_] = {{I/10 + ω, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, (-I/2 + Sqrt[3]/2) Δ, 0, 0, 0, 0},
             {-1, ω, -1, 0, 0, 0, (I/2 - Sqrt[3]/2) Δ, 0, I Δ, 0, 0, 0},
             {0, -1, ω, -1, 0, 0, 0, -I Δ, 0, (-I/2 - Sqrt[3]/2) Δ, 0, 0},
             {0, 0, -1, ω, -1, 0, 0, 0, (I/2 + Sqrt[3]/2) Δ, 0, (-I/2 + Sqrt[3]/2) Δ, 0},
             {0, 0, 0, -1, ω, -1, 0, 0, 0, (I/2 - Sqrt[3]/2) Δ, 0, I Δ},
             {0, 0, 0, 0, -1, I/10 + ω, 0, 0, 0, 0, -I Δ, 0},
             {0, (-I/2 - Sqrt[3]/2) Δ, 0, 0, 0, 0, (3/10 + I/10) + ω, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0},
             {(I/2 + Sqrt[3]/2) Δ, 0, I Δ, 0, 0, 0, -1, 3/10 + ω, -1, 0, 0, 0},
             {0, -I Δ, 0, (-I/2 + Sqrt[3]/2) Δ, 0, 0, 0, -1, 3/10 + ω, -1, 0, 0},
             {0, 0, (I/2 - Sqrt[3]/2) Δ, 0, (-I/2 - Sqrt[3]/2) Δ, 0, 0, 0, -1, 3/10 + ω, -1, 0},
             {0, 0, 0, (I/2 + Sqrt[3]/2) Δ, 0, I Δ, 0, 0, 0, -1, 3/10 + ω, -1},
             {0, 0, 0, 0, -I Δ, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, (3/10 + I/10) + ω}};
```

Inversion now works without a problem:

```
mi[ω_, Δ_] = Inverse[m[ω, Δ]];
```

The matrix is not singular:

```
Det[m[ω, Δ]]
(*    long expression    *)
```

Comment: Thank you this works well. Can you add a brief explaination, why rationalization of matrix elements works?

Comment: When things are rationalized, things are calculated with infinite precision.  On the other hand, numerical errors tend to grow with the number of multiplications, subtractions, etc.

Comment: @CraigCarter exactly. Combine this with a [poorly conditioned matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_number) and you can easily run into divergent numerical instabilities.